# Randomize two csv files but with the indexes in the same order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, random

I have two csv files, with multiple columns with text. They both have the same text, but in different languages. So for example csv1 would look like:

```
header1               header2
How are you           Good
What day is it        Friday
Whats your name       Mary
```

And csv2 would be:

```
header1               header2
Qué tal estás         Bien
Qué dia es            Viernes
Cómo te llamas        María
```

Now I want to randomize them both, but I need the translations to still be in the same order. In other words, I need the order of the indexes to be the same: if index 1 is ramdomized to be the last in csv1, I want the same for csv2:

```
header1               header2
What day is it        Friday
Whats your name       Mary
How are you           Good


header1               header2
Qué dia es            Viernes
Cómo te llamas        María
Qué tal estás         Bien
```

This is what I have done:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

data = df.sample(frac=1)
```

However with this code, both csv files end up with different orders. Is there a way to randomize the files but fixing the order of the indexes?

I apologize if something is not well explained, it's my first time both in this website and coding.

Answer (score 2):

```py
df1_shuff = df1.sample(frac=1)
df2_shuff = df2.reindex(df1_shuff.index)
```

Assuming the two `df`s started with the same, regular `RangeIndex` (which you get when doing the `pd.read_csv()` as the OP does), then the two `df_shuff` are both shuffled the same way.

I would add that the only additional line required after the OP's code is (assuming the other `df` is named `df2`, but replace as needed):

```py
data2 = df2.resample(data.index)
```

Comment: Your assumption should be that they share the same exact index; *RangeIndex* or not is irrelevant.

Comment: ...and there's also the uniquness of the index assumption. `iloc` way doesn't suffer from either of these so I'd reconsider the phrase "perfectly correct".

Comment: `RangeIndex` is what you get as index when reading the csv the way the OP has done. This doesn't make your answer incorrect. It is just a different way to get to the same result, and follows the steps the OP has already taken.